# What does the question mark mean on MDN browser compatibility table?

Tags: mobile-browser

What does the question mark mean on MDN browser compatibility table?

[image: MDN Mobile Brower compatibility table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question mark on compatibility table means anyone did not filled the 
the browser's support for the feature yet.

Simply it means "Unknown".

Check this contribution guide from MDN.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Contribute/Structures/Compatibility_tables